# Error:(32, 13) error: cannot access Referenceable class file for javax.naming.Referenceable not found

Tags: java, android

i got the error above and below is my code what am i doin wrong?
the error reference to the datasource.
what is the problem?

```
public class DBConnector {
private Connection dbConn = null;
private FileLogger fileLogger = new FileLogger("./logs/logfile.txt");
private ConfigurationReader conf = new ConfigurationReader("./config.sys");
private Logger logger = fileLogger.getLogger();

/**
 * Attempts to establish a connection with a test MySQL database.
 */
public DBConnector() {


    MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser(conf.getConfigString("username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(conf.getConfigString("password"));
    dataSource.setServerName(conf.getConfigString("dbhost"));
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(conf.getConfigString("dbname"));
    dataSource.setPort(conf.getConfigInt("dbport"));

    try {
        dbConn = dataSource.getConnection();

        logger.info("Succesful connection with database!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.info("Error: DBConnector(): problem creating database connection");
    }
    logger.info("Database connection = " + dbConn);
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, the usage of direct access to Databases over internet is discouraged on Android, this will open full access to any malware to your data. The usual solution is exposes WebAPIs as Services so you can validate server side.

Comment: currently im trying to get the code of the previous owner working on my pc. i tried to ask help of them but they said they were to busy with their study. this is for my internship ;(

Comment: This is a Android question or Java SE/EE? For Java you need to add the jndi.jar

Comment: i have added jndi.jar, but i still get the same error

Answer (score 21):

I got the same error (on Java 9 or above). For me the problem was due to a missing `requires java.naming;` directive in the `module-info.java` of my module (the module, that accesses Referenceable). Adding this directive fixed it:

```java
module MyModule {
   requires java.naming;  // Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) API.
   …
}
```

This module is for [Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Naming_and_Directory_Interface) [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API), as explained in the Javadoc for [*Module java.naming*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.naming/module-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Sander Mak [here](https://vimeo.com/241923744#t=1565s) this usually happens when your code depends on something that does not have a module descriptor and this dependency's dependency is unresolved (e.g. you're using Hibernate which has no module descriptor but it requires java.naming).

In this case, rather than polluting your own module descriptor with the transitive dependency, Sander suggests to add the transitive dependency to your module graph using

```
--add-modules java.naming
```

This way when Hibernate in the future gets its own module descriptor you can just remove the above line and have only your direct dependencies in your module-info.java.